# Type arbitrarily in a cell while using list by excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

How can I type arbitrarily in a cell while using list?

```
Public Sub PullDown()
Dim MyList(5) As String
MyList(0) = "cat"
MyList(1) = "dog"

With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
End With
End Sub
```

Because of `validation`,if I type the word such as **bird** then
it will return error cuz it's not **cat** nor **dog**.

How can I type the word arbitrarily  and choose the words I  want from list at the same time?

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot do it, the **or** in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add) is pretty explicit:

> xlValidateList - Formula1 is required, Formula2 is ignored. Formula1 must contain either a comma-delimited list of values or a worksheet reference to this list.

Still, I have tried as well:

```
Public Sub PullDown()
    Dim MyList(5) As String
    MyList(0) = "cat"
    MyList(1) = "dog"
    MyList(2) = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    With Worksheets(1).Range("C10").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
    End With
End Sub
```

So one may say that it works every time you run the code, but not the way you wanted it:

[image]